# Unable to get proper entity value

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have tried alot but I'm unable to find any solution over the internet. I am trying to get the value of a property in a collection.

This is DeliveryShop Entity:

```
[Key]
public int DeliveryShopId { get; set; }
public int MinOrderForDelivery { get; set; }
public bool HasDelivery { get; set; }
public bool HasTakeAway { get; set; }

public virtual List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
```

This is Location Entity:

```
[Key]
public int LocationId { get; set; }
public int DeliveryShopId { get; set; }
public string City { get; set; }
public string Country { get; set; }
public string ZIP { get; set; }
public virtual DeliveryShop DeliveryShop { get; set; }
```

This is my Query for index action method:

```
viewModel.DeliveryShop = db.DeliveryShops.Where(c => c.Locations.Where(l => l.City == "Berlin")).ToList();
```

I am getting an error, I want to display the shops which are only in berlin.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: What error do you get? Wouldn't it be better to go from the other side - something like `db.Locations.Where(l => l.City == "Berlin").Select(l => l.DeliveryShop)`

Comment: @Pawel no pawel, it wouldn't be better, i want to display the shops in my view which has location city name "Berlin"..please help me

Comment: Pawels comment does return all DeliveryShops with a location city named Berlin.

Comment: Also please do not say `I am getting an error`, instead please post the specific error you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LINQ doesn't make sense.  It should probably be:

```
viewModel.DeliveryShop = db.DeliveryShops
  .Where(c => c.Locations
    .Any(l => l.City == "Berlin"))
  .ToList();
```

The [LINQ Where Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) requires a `Func<TSource, bool> predicate` (a method that returns a bool).  The following code does not return a bool:

```
c.Locations.Where(l => l.City == "Berlin")
```

An alternate way to do this as [Pawel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1168070/pawel) mention in the comments is:

```
viewModel.DelipveryShop = db.Locations
  .Where(l => l.City == "Berlin") // returns IQueryable<Location>
  .Select(l => l.DeliveryShop)    // returns IQueryable<DeliveryShop>
  .ToList();  // returns List<DeliveryShop>
```